# How to set the value of nested StructuredProperty objects in Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In Python(GAE), how to set the values of "a" in the below data structure using **append**:

```
class Y(ndb.Model): 
    name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    hobby = ndb.StringProperty() 

class X(ndb.Model): 
    a = ndb.StructuredProperty(Y, repeated=True)
```

Using the below form does not work(nothing gets stored as verified in "Datastore Viewer"):

```
new_user_record = X() 
new_user_record.a.append({'name':"john", 'hobby':"painting"}) 
new_user_record.put()
```

Am i doing wrong? What is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class X(ndb.Model):
    a = ndb.StringProperty()

class Y(ndb.Model):
    b = ndd.StructuredProperty(X,repeated=True)



x = Y()
x.b = [X(a="123"),X(a="abc")]
test> x
Y(b=[X(a='123'), X(a='abc')])
```

and to append

```
test> x.b.append(X(a='xxx'))
test> x.b
[X(a='123'), X(a='abc'), X(a='xxx')]
```

See the docs, it does show you - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured